# No sound after dual boot system restart

Tags: dual-boot, sound, windows, pulseaudio, alsa

Every time I restart Linux after a Windows session on my dual boot laptop, I have no sound in Linux. After a while it suddenly returns (I haven't checked it, but I suppose, it can be related to Linux update) till the next Windows session.

inxi -Fxz gives the following output:

```
   Audio:Card Intel Device 2284 driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
   Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-93-generic
```

aplay -l output:

```
*** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice №0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice №0: subdevice #0
```

ALSA is on and not muted.

OS 1: Windows 10 (OEM-version)

OS 2: Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon Edition, 64-bit.

Laptop: Asus X541S.

In Windows sound works correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: UPD. I started Steam and sound suddenly appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had to execute the following commands to get mine to work consistently without touching it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

I then rebooted, and for the first time since getting this machine I had sound without needing to play with settings.

I grabbed this off the "First Alternative" on [this site](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) (no affiliation, just appreciated that it worked).